# Custom google map infoWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-maps

Hi
I was working on customization of gmap infoWindow.
I wrote the following code..

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAWFxfdA2Gu9LJMJw80x2tKhQhoncwM0SGfm1Opx_70t50wOiSWxRz3mt77PVPCsnMPENBxlx9FaX5AQ"></script>
<script src="javascript/extinfowindow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



var gmarkers = [];
function createMarker(point,name,html,map) {

    var myIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
    myIcon.image = "images/koodya_map_pointer.png";
    myIcon.iconSize = new GSize(22, 31);
    var markerOptions = { icon:myIcon };

    var marker = new GMarker(point,markerOptions);    

      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){ 

        marker.openExtInfoWindow(
          map,
            "extInfoWindow_coolBlues",
            "<div>"+
                "<div style='width: 78px;float:left;border:1px red solid;padding:0px'><img src='http://earth.google.com/outreach/images/mymaps_custom_icons_ss.jpg' width='77px' height='50px'/></div>"+
                "<div style='width: 130px;float:right;border:1px red solid;padding:0px'>Description Description Description Description Description Description Description</div>"+
                "<div style='border:1px red solid;padding:0px'>option option option option </div>"+
            "</div>",
          {beakOffset:1}
        ); 

      });

    return marker;
  }
```

But in Error console it showing 
Error: marker.openExtInfoWindow is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:8080/SearchEngine/list?ps=*&pt=property_type%3A*&loc=Kolkata
Line: 72

can any1 tell me why marker.openExtInfoWindow is not recognised...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for isn't openExtInfoWindow its marker.openInfoWindowHtml and you can populate that with your code above.

```
  GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml("Some other stuff");
  });
```

Check these links they are really good for getting to grips with GoogleMaps

[Info Markers Tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic1.htm)

[Google Maps Tutorials](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/)

Comment: No the function name is correct you can check it out from http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extinfowindow/docs/examples.html  
I need to customizes the whole popup not only the Text

Comment: Ok have you added the import to the ExtInfoWindow.js then?

Comment: yes you can see the 2nd line 
<script src="javascript/extinfowindow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Anyways thanks I found the error
Before I was using the google map api
at http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAWFxfdA2Gu9LJMJw80x2tKhQhoncwM0SGfm1Opx_70t50wOiSWxRz3mt77PVPCsnMPENBxlx9FaX5AQ

But it needed
http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAjU0EJWnWPMv7oQ-jjS7dYxQGj0PqsCtxKvarsoS-iqLdqZSKfxRdmoPmGl7Y9335WLC36wIGYa6o5Q

Thanks this dicussion helped me....

Comment: Sorry I looked at the error message and overlooked that line in the code. I'm posting from work so I'm doing it on the sly. Glad you got it sorted.